# Find/Delete and Update record MongoDB using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, winforms

This my doument

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57f65ed25ced690b5408a9d1"), "fbId" : "7854", "Name" : "user1", "pass" : "user1", "Watchtbl" : [ { "wid" : "745", "name" : "azs", "Symboles" : [ { "Name" : "nbv" } ] }, { "wid" : "8965", "name" : "bought stock1", "Symboles" : [ { "Name" : "AAA" }, { "Name" : "BSI" }, { "Name" : "EXXI" }, { "Name" : "AMD" } ] }, { "wid" : "9632", "name" : "bought stock3", "Symboles" : [ { "Name" : "AAA" }, { "Name" : "AMD" } ] } ] }
```

I want to find and update this record with a specific find, like I want to search by **_id** and **wid** and update the **name** and the **Symboles** of ths **Watchtbl**
But it look **_id** and **wid** are not recognized when I try to do this filtre

```
var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
var filter = builder.Eq("_id", id) & builder.Eq("wid", wid);
```

it retrun 0.

So the idea[image] is the same for Delete function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use builder.And to join clauses for your filter

```
var filter = builder.And(builder.Eq("_id", id), builder.Eq("wid", wid))
```

For updating the individual fields, you can achieve this using the

```
Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set
```

I hope this helps